# SQL - Ordering by earliest date in group

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table with a pallet id and the date it was stored.

```
690    06/30/2010
690    10/23/1989
690    06/21/2000
219    02/22/1996
219    06/25/2000
219    12/25/2012
316    06/12/2002
316    06/30/1998
316    03/26/2005
```

I want to order it by the earliest date in each group. So like this:

```
219    12/25/2012
219    06/25/2000
219    02/22/1996
690    06/30/2010
690    06/21/2000
690    10/23/1989
316    03/26/2005
316    06/12/2002
316    06/30/1998
```

How would I do this with a SQL query?

Comment: With an order by. How are you defining the order of the groups?

Comment: a simple `order by columnname, datecolumn desc` would do

Comment: ORDER BY id,date DESC

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you trying to determine which pallet is oldest?  Even your example solution can be interpreted various ways.

Answer (score 1):

just add to your select -> order by (the first criteria) storingDate desc, (then de second criteria) palletid asc (or desc as you wish).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT columnname, datecolumn
FROM tablename
ORDER BY columnname, datecolumn desc;
```